# rename spring-cloud-config native profile

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

It would be even possible to do this?

I need to deploy a spring cloud config server with property files inside the container, so I need to use the native profile, BUT in the company only allows certain profile names when running the applications.

There is a way to do some manual configuration to make a custom profile behaves like the native one?

Thanks!

Comment: No, you'd need to copy where we make `@Bean` instances under a new profile.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks [@spencergibb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2730527/spencergibb) !

This just works:

```
@EnableConfigServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class BrokernetConfigApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BrokernetConfigApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public NativeEnvironmentRepository nativeEnvironmentRepository(
            NativeEnvironmentRepositoryFactory factory,
            NativeEnvironmentProperties environmentProperties) {
        return factory.build(environmentProperties);
    }

}
```